# Login to an application URL and POST Data using Java

Tags: java, spring, httpcookie

I want to login to an authentication based application URL use those cookies/token to POST the json data to a mapping with java.

Login URL and POST URL are different and predefined in the application. (I can't change the URLs)

I tested using Postman and I can POST the data using the JSESSIONID and CSRF token from login Url but I have to do it using microservices.
I am new to java so I am not sure how to implement it. Can you please help with a sample code

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Java Http client. There are several well known 3d party Http clients out there. Basically with each one you will need to replicate the same Http requests that you sent with your postman. For each request from postman (you are talking about 2 API end-points here: Login URL and some post method for exchange of the info using the token you received in from your login call) you can see the headers that you sent and you will need to send the same headers with your Http clients of your choice. Here are some recommended Http clients:

1. Apache Http Client. See links: [HttpClient Overview](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/) and [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) - This is one of the most reliable and popular Http clients
2. OK Http Client. See links [OkHttpClient](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/), [OkHttp Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp)
3. Http client from MgntUtils library - This one is not well known client, and it does not provide all the width of functionality as the other ones, but its advantage that it is very simple in usage and it definitely would be good enough for what you need to acompllish. **Disclaimer - MgntUtils library is written and maintained by me**. Here is the [Javadoc for HttpClient class](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). The MgntUtils library can be obtained as [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc). Here is an example of code. Lets say you called the Login API and obtained the token. So a call to your post method with MgntUtils HttpClient may look as something like this:

   ```
   private static void bizServiceAdminAppTest() {
   TextUtils.setRelevantPackage("com.mgnt.stam.");
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   try {
       client.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
       client.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
       client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <token value>");
       client.setRequestHeader("cookie", "<My cookie value>");
       client.setConnectionUrl("http://my-server-address/some/path/");
       String result = client.sendHttpRequest(HttpClient.HttpMethod.POST, "{\"some key\": 317809,\n" +
               "  \"key for list of values\": [\n" +
               "  \t2154377, 564\n" +
               "  ]\n" +
               "}");
       System.out.println(client.getLastResponseCode() + " " + client.getLastResponseMessage() + "\n" + result);
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
       System.out.println(client.getLastResponseCode() + " " + client.getLastResponseMessage());
       System.out.println(TextUtils.getStacktrace(ioe));
   }
   ```

   }